# PHP DoubleEcho with IP check for bilingual web suddenly stopped working

Tags: php

Good day,

Sorry to trouble you with that, but i ran out of options already. On my Websites, right at the top of the head section, i have a PHP code that defines (or defined) that if you connect from Czech, or Slovakia (based on IP adress check) you'll get a Czech content, rest IP adresses will get english content. This is done by defining parameters for DoubleEcho function. It worked perfectly, however suddenly it stopped. Basics of the code is alright, I can still switch content manually, but automatic selection somehow crashed. I get english content all the time. Please, i would be really glad, if you can have a look at the code bellow.Thanks a lot in advance!

Tony S.

```
<?php

// Language - URL check
if(isset($_GET['en']))
  $lang = 'en';
elseif (isset($_GET['cz']))
  $lang = 'cs';
// Language - IP check
else {
  $pc = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
  $ext = array_pop(explode('.', $pc));
  if($ext == 'cz' OR $ext == 'sk')
    $lang = 'cs';
  else
    $lang = 'en';
}

    // Language - Echo function
function DoubleEcho($text_cs, $text_en)
{
  global $lang;
  if($lang == 'cs')
    echo $text_cs;
  else
    echo $text_en;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xhtml1-20000126/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>" lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="<?php echo $lang; ?>" />
```

Comment: That wouldn't work unless your IP has a reverse DNS entry. If a user visits your page with a Czech IP but no Czech hostname then that user's REMOTE_ADDR would not contain cz or sk.

Comment: You're right, thanks a lot! I just tested that with a friends. So the story is, that i've moved recently, setting up new connection and since that, the script doesn't work for me. However, friends are still ok. I wouldn't find that out on my own. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they go through a proxy or it's connected directly to a load balancer, the IP address will not vary.

This function will give you an idea of detecting the IP in more cases:

```
function getRemoteInfo () {
    $proxy="";
    $IP = "";
    if (isSet($_SERVER)) {
        if (isSet($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])) {
            $IP = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            $proxy  = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        } elseif (isSet($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])) {
            $IP = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
        } else {
            $IP = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
    } else {
        if ( getenv( 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' ) ) {
            $IP = getenv( 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' );
            $proxy = getenv( 'REMOTE_ADDR' );
        } elseif ( getenv( 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP' ) ) {
            $IP = getenv( 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP' );
        } else {
            $IP = getenv( 'REMOTE_ADDR' );
        }
    }
    if (strstr($IP, ',')) {
        $ips = explode(',', $IP);
        $IP = $ips[0];
    }
    $RemoteInfo[0]=$IP;
    $RemoteInfo[1]=@GetHostByAddr($IP);
    $RemoteInfo[2]=$proxy;
    return $RemoteInfo;
}
```

And if you want to get fancy, I wrote a fast c++ geoip daemon that works on the city level. They also have a free country-level that would work the same way.

https://github.com/homer6/geoipd

Comment: Thank you! I think i understand, just need to study that code a little bit more.  But don't want to wait with response. You're great guys! And thanks for geoip daemon link! Again many many thanks!